# Getting article create date joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to get article's created timestamp or date so I can format it with css. I've searched on google and on the forum but, I'm confused on the result.

I've done this:

```
echo $this->article->created;
echo $this->item->created;
```

And is giving me a blank result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the page layout
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/2.5.x/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php#L114

Line 114 you see how the date is rendered in 2.5.

```
<dd class="create">
<?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $this->item->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'))); ?>
</dd>
```

So to style it you can just use the create class or you can make a layout override.

This is assuming you want it in an article. If you want it in a list or something look at the appropriate layout for that. And if you want to override the date format itself do that in a layout override.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for replying... Looks like I need to modify and become confortable with default.php file.

Comment: Do not modify it.  Copy it to the html folder of your template ... e.g. templates/yourtemplatename/html/com_content/article/default.php   and make all the changes you want there.

Answer (score 0):

The element you want seems to [vary by version](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2011/item/455-How-to-put-more-love-into-your-Joomla-dates?tmpl=component&print=1), so make sure whatever you are cribbing off of, matches your installation.

Comment: I'm using the current 2.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

First of All where you are trying to display the created date.

1) In normal article views like default joomla catgory ,blog or any other view.
   You should check the following.

```
 The article options that available on the right side options of articles the created date is show true.

   Then Also make sure If it assigned to a menu there also these options available there also
   make true.
```

Then you will get the created date in the articles default view.

2)If you are trying with a custom code section you can find some codes like this.

```
$useDefList = (($params->get('show_author')) OR ($params->get('show_category')) OR ($params->get('show_parent_category'))
    OR ($params->get('show_create_date')) OR ($params->get('show_modify_date')) OR ($params->get('show_publish_date'))
    OR ($params->get('show_hits')));
```

on the article default view of joomla.In any version of joomla these should be based on article options values.

Hope this may help you...